# What is the correct export syntax for Polymer 3 mixins?

Tags: polymer

[Obsolete redacted files are removed from this question.]

**EDIT**

Since I have not received any response, I start to suspect that the possible cause of my problem comes from incorrect usage of nested mixin, which used to be working without problem under Polymer 2. Below are more complete redacted illustration of my actual files. Hopefully I will get some helps accordingly.

file **base-mixin.js**

```
/*
This annotation aims to get rid of warnings.
https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/tools/documentation#class-mixins

@polymer
@mixinFunction
@mixinClass
*/
BaseMixin=(BaseClass) => class extends BaseClass{
    static get properties(){
        return {
            p1:"v1"
        };
    }
}
```

file **child-mixin.js**

```
import "./base-mixin.js";
/*
@polymer
@mixinFunction
@mixinClass
*/
ChildMixin=(BaseClass) => class extends BaseMixin(BaseClass){
    static get properties(){
        return {
            p2:"v2"
        };
    }
    p2p1(){
        return this.p2+this.p1;
    }
}
```

file **my-app.js**

```
import {ChildMixin} from './child-mixin.js';
class MyApp extends ChildMixin(PolymerElement){
    connectedCallback(){
        super.connectedCallback();
        console.log(this.p1,this.p2,this.p2p1());
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I have removed the original redacted files from this message in order to avoid confusion.  Then I add the following files to make this project complete.

file **index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <base href="/">
        <title>Polymer 3 - Mixin</title>
        <script src="./node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
        <script src="./src/my-app.js" type="module"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <my-app>Mixin</my-app>
    </body>
</html>
```

file **polymer.json** - production version:

```
{
    "entrypoint":"index.html"
    ,"shell":"src/my-app.js"
    ,"sources":[
        "favicon.ico"
        ,"src/**/*"
    ]
    ,"extraDependencies":[
        "node_modules/@polymer/**/*"
        ,"node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/**"
    ]
    ,"lint":{
        "rules":["polymer-3"]
    }
    ,"builds":[
        {
            "preset":"es5-bundled"
            ,"addServiceWorker": false
        }
    ]
    ,"moduleResolution":"node"
    ,"npm":true
}
```

command **polymer build** on **polymer.json** "production version" produces nothing except file **polymer.json** in directory **build**. No warning or error is printed during the build.

file **polymer.json** - development version:

```
{
    "entrypoint":"index.html"
    ,"shell":"src/my-app.js"
    ,"sources":[
        "favicon.ico"
        ,"src/**/*"
    ]
    ,"extraDependencies":[
        "node_modules/@polymer/**/*"
        ,"node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/**"
    ]
    ,"lint":{
        "rules":["polymer-3"]
    }
    ,"builds":[
        { 
            "name": "dev",
            "addServiceWorker": false,
            "js": {"minify": false, "compile": false},
            "css": {"minify": false},
            "html": {"minify": false},
            "bundle": false,
            "addPushManifest": false
        }
    ]
    ,"moduleResolution":"node"
    ,"npm":true
}
```

command **polymer build** on **polymer.json** "development version" produces all expected files in directory **build** and these warnings:

```
[cli.command.build]    Clearing build/ directory...
[cli.build.build]    (dev) Building...
Could not resolve module specifier "@polymer/paper-menu-button/paper-menu-button.js" in file "/var/www/test/mixin/node_modules/@polymer/iron-list/demo/grouping.html_script_13.js".
Could not resolve module specifier "google-youtube/google-youtube.js" in file "/var/www/test/mixin/node_modules/@polymer/app-route/demo/youtube-demo/youtube-lite.js".
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of undefined as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of undefined as it exceeds the max of 500KB.
```

Reading **index.html** built with **polymer.json** "development version", browser's console shows this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ChildMixin is not defined
    at child-mixin.js:27
    at f ((index):10)
    at (index):10
    at h ((index):10)
    at (index):10
    at i ((index):10)
    at i ((index):10)
    at (index):10
    at a ((index):10)
    at c ((index):10)
```

**EDIT 3**

This question is answered at [Polymer project at GitHub](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/5258)